# Python - help on socket send error

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am doing Python training. However, the videos I am using used Python2 for the training exercises. I am working with Python3 so I am trying to convert the Python2 exercises to Python3.

I have worked through different errors, but for this error "a bytes like object is required, not builtin_function_or_method" I am not able to find solution

I keep getting the error at the server.py in the 'connection.send(self.data)' line(see image). I believe I need to convert the self.data to bytes since .send require bytes, but I do not know how to do that. I have tried encode in different areas but no success. I believe I need to encode the    "connection.send(self.data)" but I do not know how. Does anyone know what I am missing?

**Client.py**
    import socket

```
class datasave:

    def __init__(self, name = '',data = ''):
        self.name = name
        self.data = data
        return

    def load(self, connection):
        print("Self Data ",self.data)
        connection.send(self.data) 
        connection.close()
        return



import socket
PORT = 50002

files = {
"File1" : "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs" ,
"File2" : "If a woodchuck could chuck wood" ,
"File3" : "Now you're just showing off" ,
}


for i in files:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', PORT))
    s.send("SAVE".encode())
    s.send(i.encode())
    s.send(files[i].encode())
    print("check")
    s.close()

for i in files:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', PORT))
    s.send("LOAD".encode())
    s.send(i.encode())
    print("check 2")
    data = s.recv(4096).decode()
    if data != files[i]:
         print("Failed: %s != %s" % (data , files[i]))
    s.close()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', PORT))
s.send("LOAD".encode())
s.send("File4".encode())
data = s.recv(4096).decode()
if data != "File Not Found":
   print("Error check failed")
else:
   print("SUCCESS!")
s.close()
```

**server.py**

```
class datasave:
    def __init__(self, name = '',data = ''):
         print("Save")
         self.name = name
         self.data = data
         return

    def load(self, connection):
         print("LOAD Funciton")
         print("%s:\t%s" % (self.name, self.data))
         connection.send(self.data)
         connection.close()
         return

   def main():
       HOST='127.0.0.1'
       PORT = 50002
       sentinel = False
       found_file = False
       opts_list = ["SAVE","LOAD"]
       obj_list = []
       s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
       s.bind((HOST, PORT))
       s.listen(10)

while(sentinel != True):
    connection, address = s.accept()
    mode = connection.recv(4096).decode()

    if mode == opts_list[0]:
        obj = datasave(connection.recv(4096), connection.recv(4096))
        connection.close()
        obj_list.append(obj)

    elif mode == opts_list[1]:
        name = connection.recv(4096).decode()
        for obj in obj_list:
            if obj.name == name:
                obj.load(connection)
                found_file = True
        if found_file == False:
            connection.send("File Not Found").encode()
        else:
            found_file == False
    else:
        print(mode)
        sentinel = True
```

main()

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxyOE.png)

Comment: What data are you sending ? You need to use byte-string. The constructor is `b"some bytes"`

Comment: You keep getting what error?

Comment: 1. The image needs to be edited into your post as text.  2. There is clearly more code than what you have posted, and we need that too.

Comment: I will edit the post with the rest of the code.The error is on the image: on connection.send(self.data) line and it is 'a bytes-like object is required, not 'builtin_function_or_method'